# Problems Saving workspace in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, metadata, eclipse-metadata

i Just deleted all projects from the following folder

```
 C:\Users\admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects
```

After that i always got error message "C:\Users\admin\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects"

Comment: Why did you delete that? This contains critical data for your workspace.

Comment: In eclipse always shows loading...

Answer (score 0):

That is the meta data fro your projects, and critical data. The workspace where your code is saved is the path that comes up everytime you start eclipse. I would just reinstall eclipse to make sure to get everything back in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the workspace by doing the following.
Right click on package explorer and choose "switch workspace" and then select new directory.